# Python on anaconda/ Jupyter notebook not respond to 'import tensorflow' (no errors)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter

I am new to TensorFlow. I trained several models past days using tensorFlow-gpu by using GPU (using CUDA) successfully. But when I checked recently, python on anaconda not respond to 'import tensorflow'. It takes much time and exit python on conda prompt. No errors are displayed.

I checked import tensorflow in the jupyter notebook but it did not give an output. 
I also tried conda install tensorflow-gpu again, it says that i have tensorflow-gpu in my environment.
I have deleted cache on the environment by conda clean -a
but coud not help.

No error messages. it just exits on the python and returns to the conda prompt without any messages. Due to this reason, I even can not find what the problem is.
[python on anaconda prompt when import tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyV4r.jpg)

Comment: I'd try to remove the entire conda environment and recreate it. There is a similar issue here without a solution: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8676

Comment: Oh thanks... I did same and now there is no problem...